# Simplify each coefficient of coefficientlist individually and automatically substitute any repeats

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have a 13x13 polynomial coefficient list that I create with:

```
    CoefficientList[Expand[myequation] /. Equal -> Subtract,{x,z}]
```

I would now like to simplify each coefficient and to automatically replace repeats (e.g. automatic substitution)

For example, let's say two of my coefficents are:

`a*b^2*c^2` and `d*b^2*c`

I would like mathematica to detect b^2*c as a repeat and automatically substitute it with a new variable

Which commands do I need to look up for this?

Edit: each coefficient is as summation of multiplicative terms, each weighted with a number

Comment: Are all your terms simple products of variables? Are there numbers as well? Are there sums as well? The algorithm may depend on the details. If you can give `myequation` you'll get better answers.

Comment: Almost: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{a*b^2*c^2 , d*b^2*c}][[1, -1, -1]]``

Comment: What if the input is `{a*b^2*c^2, d*b^2*c, a d b^2}`?